# Can't get key from value within an object

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the value associated with a key and create a new object, such as below. However when I assign the value of `employeeCountryName` to the object `newCountryList`, i get `employeeCountryName` returned and not "United Kingdom".

Any thoughts why this may be?

```
   const countryList = {
        "United Kingdom": "GBR"
    };

    const employeeCountryCode = "GBP"

    const getKey = (obj, val) => Object.keys(obj).find(key => obj[key] === val);

    const employeeCountryName = getKey(countryList, employeeCountryCode);

    const newCountryList = {
        employeeCountryName: employeeCountryCode
    };
```

Comment: `employeeCountryName` is a _key_ of your object, as defined - it is not based on your predefined variable. If you want the value inside a variable to be used as key, you need to tell JS to interpret it as such: `{ [employeeCountryName]: employeeCountryCode }`

Comment: This is a typo, `const employeeCountryCode = "GBP"` with `P`, but the `"United Kingdom"` value is `"GBR"` with `R`

Comment: just a typo in the code above and not in the source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind that when you define an object, it's keys aren't based on any other variables by default, they are just strings taken as keys. In order to tell javascript to take the value of a variable you have predefined instead of using it directly as a key, you need to add `[]` around them like this:

```
const variableName = 'keyToUse';
const object = { [variableName]: 1 } // { keyToUse: 1 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like that;

```
const newCountryList = {
        [employeeCountryName]: employeeCountryCode
    };
```

By the way, in your case find function couldn't find any key-value pair so it returns undefined. Because "United Kingdom" field has a GBR value and you're trying to find GBP

Comment: Thanks, works well.

BTW GBP just a typo in the code above and not in the source code.